# Closure Compiler renaming function in extern

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I'm trying to create an extern for Electron that gets used by the Google Closure Compiler. This is what my externs look like:

```
var electron = {};
electron.dialog = function() {};
electron.app = function() {};
electron.ipcRenderer = function() {};
electron.on = function() {};
electron.send = function() {};
electron.remote = function(){}; // {return{getGlobal: function(){}}};
electron.remote.getGlobal = function(a){};
electron.require = function() {};
electron.buildFromTemplate = function() {};
electron.popup = function() {};
electron.getCurrentWindow = function() {};
electron.showErrorBox = function() {};
electron.setTitle = function() {};
electron.setRepresentedFilename = function() {};
electron.showMessageBox = function() {};
electron.getPath = function() {};
electron.showSaveDialog = function() {};
electron.showOpenDialog = function() {};

var process = {
    platform: {}
};
```

The problem I am having is that the compiler is not retaining the function name for the getGlobal function. My original source code looks like this:

```
const electron = require('electron');
electron.remote.getGlobal('sharedObject')
```

After running the compiler, it ends up looking like this:

```
var a = require("electron");
console.log(a.remote.D("sharedObject"));
```

a.remote.D should really be a.remote.getGlobal

How can I get the compiler to retain the getGlobal function name?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my original source code to now look like this:

> electron.remote'getGlobal'

The compiler will retain the name. This is because the compiler always keeps strings intact. The compile code now looks like this:

```
console.log(a.remote.getGlobal("sharedObject"));
```

It is still a mystery though why the compiler doesn't recognize the getGlobal function in the extern file. Maybe it can only handle functions that are nested one level deep from their root object (whereas here, it's two levels). Another reason may have to do with how the compiler carries out its multiphase compiling which is somewhat flawed in treating nested functions.